# Finding the missing term, in matrix arrangement

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Find the  missing term $x$. I am not able to guess the pattern $$\begin{pmatrix}811 & 236 & 57 \\ 23 & 87 & 119\\ 314 & 70 & x\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why are you interested in this question? If you say "pattern" in general, any value fits.

Comment: Questions like this often get comments saying it could be anything, which is true.  I like puzzles like this, but believe the rule has to be simple enough that when you find or hear it you say "of course".  $3 \times 3$ grids are hard to make into good puzzles because there is so much structure it is hard to figure out what to pay attention to-rows? columns?.  There are too few numbers to see the pattern.

Comment: If [this](https://doubt.dubbtr.com/topic/3397/inserting-the-missing-character-matrix) is the original source, than maybe someone just put random numbers in a matrix.

Comment: This is an extremely poor question that does not belong on MSE. Perhaps try Puzzling SE.

Comment: @James We are finding the missing term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transposition of digits of one operand allows to build the chain of summations:
\begin{align}
&\mathbf{118}+\mathbf{118} = 236,\quad 236+\mathbf{78} = 314,\quad 57+87 = \mathbf{134}, \quad\mathbf{32}+87=119\dots
\end{align}
Term $\underline{x=94}$ allows to close the chain:
$$94+87 = \mathbf{181},\quad \mathbf{49} + 70 = 119,\quad 87+\mathbf{7}= 94.$$

Answer (score 0):

I found the same question [here](https://doubt.dubbtr.com/topic/3397/inserting-the-missing-character-matrix) where it was multiple choice.  The choices were $87,12,57,61$.  Two people chose $87$.  The only one who presented a reason said to add the digits of each number until you are down to a single digit.  Equivalently, reduce each number $\bmod 9$.  Then the third column is the sum of the first two.  Without the choices this is not enough to pick $87$, you just know you want something equivalent to $6 \bmod 9$.  The only choice that fits is $87$.  The setter claims the answer is $61$ but does not provide the reason.  That is the most credible source I can find.

Answer (score 0):

The term "pattern" is not a mathematical, precisely-defined, rigorous term.

Therefore, the question has no sense.

If you want to answer it correctly, you can answer : "I found the missing term $x$, it is at the bottom right of the matrix. Have you any maths questions ? Thanks !".

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I found the missing term $x$ at the bottom right of the matrix, it is $94\dots$

Comment: Great job ! But my point is that you could find a logic for absolutely *any* value of $x$... So, even if your solution is elegant, I still think this kind of question is not interesting. And by the way... I'm not Ross Millikan :)

Comment: This is a suitable place for the discussions. Such tasks are a challenge to the associative thinking of mathematics. One day, Gilbert said about someone: "He became a poet. For a mathematician, he lacked imagination."

Comment: I understand that, but your quotation is not : "He became a mathematician. For a poet, he lacked rigorousness." In maths, when a thing is not well-defined, it has no sense. Otherwise... it's poetry.

Comment: In the problem statement, the word "term" has a rigorous mathematical meaning.

Comment: Maybe, but not the word "pattern".